# Is there a PHP library to auth SFTP using user, password AND private/public key?

Tags: php, ssh, sftp, lib

I tried https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpseclib/ but i did not have success on it.
So i'll be glad if anyone knows any other way to do that

Using this command on cmd it works to connect but i want it on PHP:

sshpass -p password sftp -c aes128-cbc -i ~/dir_to_id_rsa.ppk -P 2222 user@host

PHP 5.6.3

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use phpseclib v3, which is installable via Composer and works with PHP 5.6. Example:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib3\Net\SSH2;
use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;

$key = PublicKeyLoader::load(file_get_contents('privatekey'));

$ssh = new SSH2('localhost');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password', $key)) {
    throw new \Exception('Login failed');
}
```

If you're using phpseclib v1 then unless you're using the latest git version of phpseclib the order that you have the key and password in matter.

Anyway, I'd say post your phpseclib code and I can help you out with that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the v3 using composer:
1. I've run this command: composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~3.0
2. Then it was installed successfully.
3. When executing your code i'm getting this:

Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /var/www/html/vendor/paragonie/constant_time_encoding/src/Base64.php on line 2

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /var/www/html/vendor/paragonie/constant_time_encoding/src/Base64.php on line 45

I'm using composer 1 to install this (which is deprecated), should be a problem?

Comment: @LeonardoSoares - my guess is that you did `composer install` with a newer version of PHP then your web server is running. https://phpseclib.com/docs/install talks about this general strategy in more detail. That said, https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/releases/download/3.0.12/phpseclib3.0.12.zip was just added to the phpseclib 3.0.12 release. Try that out and see if it works for you. Be sure to do `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` at the top of your file.